# How to run a Desktop Shortcut key while the shortcut is hidden?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, batch, hotkeys, hidden-file

I have a batch file for a particular task which I want to access using a Keyboard hotkey. I made a desktop shortcut of the batch file and assigned it Hotkey in the Properties. But I don't want to keep the shortcut on my desktop because it doesn't look nice. So I made it hidden by:

```
attrib +h example.bat
```

What I noticed is that it works for time being, but as soon as you restart the pc, it stops working thereafter. What can I do so that it works permanently with still being hidden.

P.S. I don't want to use AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving the shortcut to your start menu. The keyboard shortcut will work from there fine too, but that way the file is not on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that won't work for me. I require the shortcut to be on the desktop and hidden.

Comment: That is a combination that won't work either.